# How to get LookupValue in ItemUpdating

Tags: 2010, lookup-column, event-handlers

I have a custom EventHandler for `ItemUpdating` on a list which has a Lookup column.

If I look in the `properties.AfterProperties` for the column in the `ItemUpdating` event I get the `LookupId` value but not the `LookupValue` value.

I need the `LookupValue` from this column in order for the rest of the logic I've implemented in the EventHandler to work.

Why is the `LookupValue` empty and the `LookupId` not?
And how can I get the `LookupValue` at this stage then?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a new SPFieldLookUp

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfieldlookup.aspx

and cast the context item to that object.  Then you will have the SPFieldLookupValue object available to work with and you can get the value of that field in multiple contexts.

Something like this should work
https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/devwiki/sp2007dev/pages/setting%20and%20getting%20field%20values%20of%20type%20spfielduser,%20spfieldurl%20and%20spfieldlookup%20using%20extension%20methods.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If the List Item (objItem in this example) is populated:

```
string s = new SPFieldLookupValue(objItem["MyField"].ToString()).LookupValue;
```